# Searching for a file in specific folder, with specific extension containing specific word

Tags: windows, windows-search, file-search

I know I created a file in November / December 2021. I know it contained a specific word and I also know its extension. Also I know its folder. But the folder has many subdirectories. How can I narrow down the search to lesser files in Windows? What is the best tool?

Answer (score 2):

I fell in love with 'Everything' the moment I found it:

https://www.voidtools.com/

Assume I need to locate a file with 'smart' in name, while extension is PDF, I type "smart pdf" (without quotes) in search bar and virtually immediately see all files that fit this filter.

[image]

Comment: yeah I love Everything too. But I want to search text in file contents, not file names. I guess I should be searching from `grep` equivalent, but seems that its not straight forward as `grep`, need to use some hack?

Comment: Ahhhhh, well Everything does that too in advanced search but I do not know how efficient it is.

Comment: @Maha I would still give Everything a try, as it [supports content searching](https://www.voidtools.com/support/everything/searching/#content-searching:~:text=Advanced%20Search.-,Content%20Searching,-Warning%3A%20content%20searching) and in combination with the criteria for extension and folder it should not take too long. I just tried it, and in a parentfolder of 105k files in 15k folders the query `my_folder\ *.py content:"import pandas as pd"` took less than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

There are many third-party search utilities for Widows. Mythicsoft's [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/), shown below, is a good free, *non*indexed, search tool:

[image: Agent Ransack]

A useful free, open source, tool that *indexes* files and email message is [DocFetcher](https://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html).

There are [many alternative search utilities](https://alternativeto.net/software/docfetcher/), any of which could satisfy your requirements.